# Can't display blob image in jsp in Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I save and load image to `MySQL 5.5` database via `Hibernate` as `byte[]` in java and `blob` in database. Nevertheless when I can't display it in `jsp`.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/productPicture/{productPictureId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String productPictureEditGET(@PathVariable("productPictureId") int productPictureId, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

    ProductPictureFormBO productPicture = productPictureService.getById(productPictureId, ProductPictureFormBO.class, ProductPictureEntity.class);

    byte[] encoded=org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
            .encodeBase64(productPicture.getPicture());
    String encodedString = new String(encoded);

    model.addAttribute("image",encodedString);
    model.addAttribute("productPicture", productPicture);

    return "productPicture/editView";
}
```

and then in jsp both elements don't display anything...:

```
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}" alt="..." width="200" height="200">`
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${productPicture.picture}" width="200" height="200">`
```

Result in jsp:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,MTA4ODg4MTdfMTAyMDM1NjkyNTEzMzQ1MThfNzg0MzE4ODI3Mjc5Mjk0NTQ3MF9uLmpwZw=="  width="200" height="200">
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[B@1666a2e3" width="200" height="200">
```

Any idea what I'm missing and how to fix it?

Comment: What is actually being generated in the result HTML?

Comment: You probably should tell us what's inside `image` (assuming it's not too big). Or share a screenshot showing the generated DOM..

Comment: Do you need to display them as data urls as opposed to regular images?

Comment: Oh! You're completly right! The problem is not in this display view, but in the save event, where I save just a name of uploaded image and not the image itself! :) Thank you for helping me to figure out what's going on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data URI scheme must represent the image's content, not some string representing a file name.

Here,

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,MTA4ODg4MTdfMTAyMDM1NjkyNTEzMzQ1MThfNzg0MzE4ODI3Mjc5Mjk0NTQ3MF9uLmpwZw=="  width="200" height="200">
```

this is the base64-encoded value of `10888817_10203569251334518_7843188272792945470_n.jpg`, which doesn't represent the image content at all, but clearly the image's filename. Apparently the `ProductPicture#getPicture()` returns the sole filename as `byte[]` instead of the image's content.

So, either you saved the image the wrong way by only saving the image's file name instead of image's content in the DB, or you used the wrong model value (although I'd wonder what's the point of saving the file name as `byte[]` instead of directly as `String`).

Comment: Yes, I saved just the filename isntead of the file itself